# Are there any ways to select a CSS class with JS that doesn't exist in DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, css, element, selector

Is it possible to select a CSS `class` with JS which is **registered** only in its file, not exist in DOM?

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('class2')[0],
    getStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elem),
    value = getStyle.getPropertyValue('top');
console.log(value);
// Can't get the value of class2 because it doesn't exist in DOM.
```

```css
.class1 {
  top: 10px;
}
.class2 {
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">
  top
</div>
```

Like this example, There's no problem to select the `.class1` because it's exist in DOM within an element.

But I want to access the `.class2` which doesn't exist inside of DOM.

Are there any ways to do this?

Comment: How is the `.class2` when *not* in the DOM created? Can you give an example?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Maybe I misunderstood about what is DOM. I wanted to select a specific class(`.class2`, in this case) whatever it's created with an element in HTML or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XY Problem here... You are not willing to get an element, but the value that is set in the stylesheets.

Even if this may be possible (it, is, but very convoluted) there is a big flaw in that approach: **Because a CSS rules exists doesn't mean it will get applied**.

For instance in your case, the `.class2` rule indeed exists and is active, however, since no element matches this rule, it won't have any effect.
The same way, even if an element did match this rule, it could very well get overridden by an other rule:

```js
console.log(
  getComputedStyle(
    document.querySelector('.class2')
  ).getPropertyValue('top')
); // "10px"
```

```css
#foo { top: 10px };
.class2 { top: 50px; }
```

```html
<div class="class2" id="foo"></div>
```

So, yes, you could get the set value of the CSSRule:

```js
const matching_rules = [...document.styleSheets].reduce((matched, sheet) => {
  [...sheet.cssRules].forEach( r => {
      if(r.selectorText && r.selectorText.includes('.class2'))
        matched.push(r.style.top);
  });
  return matched;
}, []);
console.log(matching_rules);
```

```css
.class2 { top: 50px; }
```

But once again, that is really not useful, and most of the time, you just need to call `getComputedStyle` once your element has been attached to the DOM (it's useless to call it before, since no CSS rule are applied on elements that are not displayed.

```js
const elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.classList.add('class2');
console.log('matches:', elem.matches('.class2')); // true
const comp = getComputedStyle(elem);
console.log('computed top:', JSON.stringify(comp.getPropertyValue('top'))); // "" (the default)
```

```css
.class2 {
  top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Well, parseInt() will do the job for converting the string to an integer, so no problem. Thank you for answering :-)

Answer (score 1):

The only possible way to access such an element would be to have a reference to it or one of its parent elements beforehand. The usual way would be to use the element reference created from `document.createElement`, or by whichever way the element was created:

```js
const element = document.createElement('div');
element.className = 'class2';

// element is not attached to the DOM, but you can still reference it here

// you can also retrieve elements created by assigning to the innerHTML of another element:
element.innerHTML = '<div class="class2"></div>';
const element2 = element.children[0];

// element2 is not attached to the DOM, but you can still reference it here
```

If you can't see where the element is created, these methods won't work. In that case, your only other option is to monkeypatch the various methods that can create elements *before* the script that creates the elements runs, (such as `createElement`, `innerHTML` setter, `outerHTML` setter, etc) but this is almost always a very bad idea unless there's no other option (like if you're writing a userscript).

Comment: If you can't see where the element is created, these methods won't work - Well, then I'm gonna find the other ways. Thank you for answering.